# How to create dynamic array in java with unclear and diffrent inpu INDEXes?

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, indexing

I am new to Java and I needed dynamic Array ... all of thing I found that's for dynamic Array we should use "Array List' that's ok but when I want the indexes to be the power of X that given from input , I face ERORR ! .. the indexes are unclear and the are not specified what is the first or 2th power ! .... can anyone help me how solve it?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner Reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Float> Zarayeb = new ArrayList<Float>();  
    Float s ;
    int m;
    System.out.print("Add Count of equation Sentences : ");
    int N = Reader.nextInt();
    if (N == 0)
            return;
    for (int i = 0; i < N  ; i++) {
        s = Reader.nextFloat() ;
        System.out.print("x^");
        m = Reader.nextInt();
        if (Zarayeb.get(m)== null)
            Zarayeb.add(0 , s);
        else{
            Float l ;
            l = Zarayeb.get(m);
            Zarayeb.add (m , l+s);
        }
        if (i < N-1)
            System.out.print("\r+");
    }
    System.out.print("Add Count of equation Sentences : ");
    N = Reader.nextInt();
    if (N == 0)
            return;
    for (int i = 0; i < N  ; i++) {
        s = Reader.nextFloat() ;
        System.out.print("x^");
        m = Reader.nextInt();
        if (Zarayeb.get(m)== null)
            Zarayeb.add(m , s);
        else{
            Float l ;
            l = Zarayeb.get(m);
            Zarayeb.add (m , l+s);
        }
        if (i < N-1)
            System.out.print("\r+");
    }
    System.out.print("Enter X: ");
    float X = Reader.nextFloat();
    float Sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Zarayeb.size();i++) {
    Sum += (Zarayeb.get(i) * Math.pow(X,i));
}
System.out.println("\nThe final answer is : " + Sum);
```

Comment: `when I want the indexes were the power of X that given from input the program comes with error .. the indexes are unclear and that is not specified what is the first or 2th power ` is not clear at all, please rephrase.

Comment: `, I face ERORR ! ..` what error? copy the exact error (and if it's run time - the full stack trace)

Comment: @Sami why did you unaccept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First I refactored your code a bit to make sense of it:

Main class with the top level logic:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private Scanner scanner;
    private final Totals totals = new Totals();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Main app = new Main();
        app.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            readAndProcessEquationSentences();
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }

    private void readAndProcessEquationSentences() {
        readSentences(true);
        readSentences(false);
        System.out.println("The final answer is : " + totals.calculateSum(readBaseInput()));
    }

    private void readSentences(final boolean useInitialLogic) {
        System.out.print("Enter number of equation sentences:");
        final int numberOfSentences = scanner.nextInt();
        if (numberOfSentences == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No sentences");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSentences; i++) {
            Sentence sentence = Sentence.read(scanner);
            if (useInitialLogic) {
                totals.addInitialSentence(sentence);
            } else {
                totals.addNextSentence(sentence);
            }
            if (i < numberOfSentences - 1) {
                System.out.print("\r+");
            }
        }
    }

    private float readBaseInput() {
        System.out.print("Enter base: ");
        return scanner.nextFloat();
    }
}
```

Sentence class which represents one equation sentence entered by the user:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sentence {
    private Float x;
    private int y;

    public static Sentence read(final Scanner scanner) {
        final Sentence sentence = new Sentence();
        System.out.println("Enter x^y");
        System.out.print("x=");
        sentence.x = scanner.nextFloat();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("y=");
        sentence.y = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        return sentence;
    }

    public Float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Totals class which keeps track of the totals:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Totals {

    private final List<Float> values = new ArrayList<Float>();

    public void addInitialSentence(final Sentence sentence) {
        if (values.size() <= sentence.getY()) {
            addToStart(sentence);
        } else {
            addToValue(sentence);
        }
    }

    private void addToStart(final Sentence sentence) {
        values.add(0, sentence.getX());
    }

    public void addNextSentence(final Sentence sentence) {
        if (values.size() <= sentence.getY()) {
            values.add(sentence.getY(), sentence.getX());
        } else {
            addToValue(sentence);
        }
    }

    private void addToValue(final Sentence sentence) {
        Float total = values.get(sentence.getY());
        total = total + sentence.getX();
        values.add(sentence.getY(), total);
    }

    public float calculateSum(final float base) {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            sum += (values.get(i) * Math.pow(base, i));
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I don't have the foggiest idea what this is supposed to do. I named the variables according to this foggy idea.

You are letting the user input values in two separate loops, with a slightly different logic I called 'initial' and 'next'.

In the initial loop you were doing this:

```
    if (Zarayeb.get(m) == null)
        Zarayeb.add(0 , s);
```

In the next loop this:

```
    if (Zarayeb.get(m) == null)
        Zarayeb.add(m , s);
```

There are problems with this because the ArrayList.get(m) will throw an IndexOutOfBoundException if m is out or range. So I changed that to the equivalent of:

```
    if (Zarayeb.size() <= m) {
        ....
    }
```

However, in the 'next' case this still does not solve it. What should happen in the second loop when an 'm' value is entered for which no element yet exists in the ArrayList?

Why do you need to enter sentences in two loops?

What is the logic supposed to achieve exactly?